# What is the font used on Instagram story?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Just looking to see if anyone knows what the font is that Instagram stories is using for their "modern" typeface?

Here's an example that says "how artsy" in the modern font on Instagram's stories.

[image]

Comment: There's no image example.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the font in your question so we may be better able to help?

Comment: WhatTheFont already have this case: https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/case/1401830/

Comment: @Clicker The WTF case is 17 days old; this question is about 45 days old, so the WTF case wasn’t there when this was asked (and answered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar: [Rift Soft Medium](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/fort-foundry/rift/rift-soft) via fontspring.com

[image]

Similar: [Tungsten Rounded Book](https://try.typography.com/?font=100052) via typography.com.

Used as main font at [ilovetypography.com](https://ilovetypography.com/).

[image: tungsten]

Comment: Close but not quite

Comment: No, I guess is Instagram's own design. Didn't see anyone with the same R.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite similar to [Solido Condensed Book](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/dstype/solido-condensed/book/), from Myfonts:

[image: Solido Condensed Book]

This is slightly more rounded, but the R and the S are the right basic shape. Unfortunately Myfonts don't have a "write your own example" for this font, so I was stuck with the cod-Latin text.

Comment: The R is not even close in my opinion.

Comment: @Scott I think you meant to put that comment on the other answer.

Comment: No Andrew, I know exactly where I placed it. The R is *clearly* incorrect to my eyes. Your sample has an R with an outward curve on the tail. The original has a straight tail on the R. You are correct that the S is pretty darn close. But the R is [considerably different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6NVT.png).

Comment: Hmm. Well, not as different as the other suggestion present when I made this one. I think that comment is unfair. To say it's "not even close" is just plain wrong. It *is* close, as your example demonstrates.

Comment: "*...in my opinion*" -- it's a valid statement. **I** don't think the R is anywhere close. You are, naturally, free to disagree.

Answer (score 2):

This font is actually [Aveny T Regular](https://www.a2-type.co.uk/aveny-t) by A2-TYPE, a variant on a font originally made for a theatre in Copenhagen:

[image: Aveny-T font sample]

[This blog post](http://thatleomartinez.com/instagram-stories-font) has a run-through of the different fonts used in Instagram stories.

Comment: Please note that answers to font identification questions should include an image of the font. It’s also a good idea to make it clear what you’re linking to (in this case it was a blog post), and to include a direct link to the foundry/font itself. I’ve suggested an edit to incorporate all these things into your answer.